# How to 'fetch' multiple selected ranges within an active sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to select multiple ranges within a single column of my active sheet, and then have a script write values to the adjacent cells of each range. I've chosen to use the following to fetch a list of all the selected ranges:

```
   var ranges = active_tab.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
```

I select the ranges manually using the mouse/ keyboard:
[image]

My problem however is that this seems to only return a list containing one range object as its only element. This range object corresponds to the first selected range.

Is there a better way to fetch all of the selected ranges at once?

Once I have the proper ranges, this code is run:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++){
    var range = ranges[i];
    var num_rows = range.getNumRows();
    var last_row = range.getLastRow();
    var starting_row = 1 + last_row - num_rows;

    for (var i = starting_row; i < (starting_row + num_rows); i++){
      active_tab.getRange(i, 4, 1, (values_by_space_type[current_space_type].length + 1))
          .setFontColor('green');
      active_tab.getRange(i, 5, 1, values_by_space_type[current_space_type].length)
          .setValues([values_by_space_type[current_space_type]])
    }
```

Comment: Try explicitly casting the `Selection` first: `active_tab.getSelection().getActiveRangeList()`

Comment: I tried that but still the same result. Thanks though.

Comment: add to your question a screenshot / instruction set for how you are selecting the ranges. You might also check the Apps Script issue tracker to see if this is a known issue

Comment: What's in `values_by_space_type`? I just tried out a simplified version of your code, wherein I just called `setFontColor` on each range, and it worked fine with multiple selections.

Comment: `values_by_space_type` is a set of key/value pairs where the keys are space type names (i.e 'Dormitory - Living Quarters'- taken from screenshot in the question) and the corresponding value is an array of three elements that needs to be written to the adjacent cells. As an example: `values_by_space_type["Dormitory - Living Quarters"] = [25, 4.1, 2.5]`

Comment: There has been a bug reported to Google [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946)